# Using define directive to get the namespace name

Tags: c++

Having such a simple C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define NS NS_Static
#define MAKESTRING(x) #x

namespace NS {
  int global_x = 8;
  void print_global_x() {
    std::cout << MAKESTRING(NS) << "::global_x: " << global_x << std::endl;
  }
}
```

I'h expected to get on output `NS_Static::global_x: 8` BUT getting just `NS::global_x: 8`. I've asked a similar question earlier and the user *Eljay* provided me an answer to use such an extra code:

```
#define NS Static
#define MAKESTRING_HELPER(x) #x
#define MAKESTRING(x) MAKESTRING_HELPER(x)
```

It finally works but can someone please explain my why my original approach doesn't work?

Shouldn't the preprocessor (in my original approach) AT FIRST (since it's the first macro defined) run `NS NS_Static` macro resulting in
`NS_Static` and then pass that `NS_Static` to the stringizing `MAKESTRING(x) #x` macro resulting in expected `NS_Static` *string*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how [stringizing](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html#Stringizing) (`#x`) in the C preprocessor works.

> Unlike normal parameter replacement, the argument is not macro-expanded first.

To get the parameter to macro-expand, add another layer of indirection (a no-op macro like you've discovered, will suffice).

Comment: So when just provide `MAKESTRING(NS)` as in my original approach the preprocessor DOESN'T substitute the `NS` by `NS_Static` but just pass the `NS` to the `MAKESTRING` macro resulting in simply `NS`?

Answer (score 3):

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html#Argument-Prescan

> Macro arguments are completely macro-expanded before they are substituted into a macro body, unless they are **stringized** or pasted with other tokens.

In your original function:

```
#define NS NS_Static
#define MAKESTRING(x) #x
```

The marco argument is **stringized**, so `NS` will not be replaced by  `NS_Static`.